# Flutter Inject parts of Widget into parent preserving controllers and state

Tags: flutter, widget, inject

I am looking for a way to build a widget that creates a scroll controller and contains several widgets that all depend on that scroll controller.

Instead of rendering the whole widget I want to place the widgets that it contains inside a parent widget in their corresponding places whilst still connected to that scroll controller.

**EDIT//**
In laymen's terms, I want to declare a widget wherever I happen to declare it but not actually render it there. It should render instead in a targeted location but still maintain any state or controllers it obtained or inherited from the position in which it was actually declare. IF this can be done it is probably far simpler than what I have tried to outline here.
**//**

```
// Parent Widget

    class ParentReceiver extends StatelessWidget {
      const ParentReceiver({super.key});
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: // expects to receive InjectWidget's MyHeaderWidget() here.
            ),
// expects to receive InjectWidget's MyContentWidget() here.
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: // expects to receive InjectWidget's MyFooterWidget() here.
            ),
          ]
        );
      }
    }

class InjectWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const InjectWidget({super.key});
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    ScrollController scrollController = useScrollController(); 
    // yes that's a hook but it doesn't matter how I got the scroll controller.

    return Stack(
      children: [
        MyHeaderWidget(scrollController: scrollController);
        MyContentWidget(scrollController: scrollController);
        MyFooterWidget(scrollController: scrollController);
      ],  
    );

  }
}

class MyContentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyContentWidget({super.key, required scrollController,});
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return ListView(
      controller: scrollController,
      children: [
         etc...
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

So `MyHeaderWidget`, `MyFooterWidget` and `MyContentWidget` all used the scroll controller that was created by `InjectWidget`. However, `InjectWidget` is not to render directly. These three individual widgets with their scroll controller intact should be placed into the corresponding areas of the `ParentReceiver` Widget.

The basic premise behind this is to build entire widgets that respond to controllers but place various component parts of them into the parent view.

Comment: I appreciate this may be a badly worded attempt to explain what may be a simpler concept. Would Overlay allow one to preserve the existing controllers of a widget but render it elsewhere?